# vertical scrolling datetime picker library

Tags: android, datetimepicker

Not sure if this is the right place to ask, but since I ask almost everything about programming or anything that's related to it here, so here it goes..

I'm very fond of this clean and simple date-time picker in lalamove, so I tried searching around in android-arsenal if I can find a library which does this, but to my surprise, I couldn't find any. So I'm trying my luck here, do anyone here knows if there's an android library that's similar to this? Of course, it doesn't look hard to develop it myself, but a library would be much faster choice

[image]